# How to force a redirect except for certain values with an encrypted php script?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Im using a commercial ioncube encrypted php script. I have a script **cart.php** that accepts a range of values such as cart.php?a=checkout, cart.php?a=complete, cart.php?a=view etc. However, I only want the script to run when two values are specified i.e. a=checkout or a=complete. For all other values or if no value is specified I want it to redirect to our pricing page - pricing.php. Is this possible using mod_rewrite - redirecting all but some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\ba=(complete|view)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cart.php
RewriteRule .* pricing.php
```